# How to sort dynamic list items based on numerical values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

This is stressing me up!

Am building an app that lists a number of office locations.

The app picks the user's location and calculates the distance between him and all the offices.

Now I need to sort the lists based on their distance from the user in ascending order.

Now the li items are created dynamically in the ul when the app loads by the javascript.

My app connects and fetches the data of the various offices from firebase.

The distance, however, is created on the client-side and I need to sort the list items (offices) based on that distance.

Nearest Location

```
<!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="all-parishes">
                <ul id="all-parishes" style="padding: 0; list-style: none; ">

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<script>
    //Distance Calculation
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDXtwlWjWygp_sGx9R1qk-4gDuH9ZEx9xg",
        authDomain: "parish-connect.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://parish-connect.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "parish-connect",
        storageBucket: "parish-connect.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "304974921983",
        appId: "1:304974921983:web:9ac09b834259488951ccca",
        measurementId: "G-QWLPQ52Z7S"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var db = firebase.firestore();

    var lat1, lon1;

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    getLocation();

    function showPosition(position) {
        lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
        lon1 = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lat1);
        console.log(lon1);

        // To do: The code below creates a dynamic list items (<li>) and prints to the
        // <ul> container. I want to be able to sort the lists in ascending/descending order based on
        //the distances <p class="distance">${calcDistance(doc.data().lat, doc.data().lng).toFixed(5)} km away</p>
        var text = "";
        db.collection("parish-ghana").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                text += `
        <li>
        <div class="card demo-card-header-pic">
            <div style="background-image:url(${doc.data().pic_url})" valign="bottom" class="card-header"></div>
            <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
            <p class="parish-item">${doc.data().name}</p>
            <p class="distance">${calcDistance(doc.data().lat, doc.data().lng).toFixed(5)} km away</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <hr>
        `
            });

            document.getElementById("all-parishes").innerHTML = text;

        });
    }
    //End to do


    //When the location throws an error
    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    //Function to calculate distances
    function calcDistance(lat2, lon2) {

        function toRad(x) {
            return x * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        var R = 6371; // km 
        var dLat = toRad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;
        return d;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first map your querySnapshot to a plain array of data objects, and add the `distance` as an additional property to each object. Then sort that array by that new property. Finally perform the loop as you already had it (with slight changes to the dynamic expressions). I would also use a `.map()` for that loop and then `.join` the pieces of HTML together with `<hr>`.

Here is how that looks:

```
db.collection("parish-ghana").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    document.getElementById("all-parishes").innerHTML = querySnapshot.docs
    .map(doc => doc.data())
    .map(data => ({
        ...data,
        distance: calcDistance(data.lat, data.lng)
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
    .map(data => `
    <li>
        <div class="card demo-card-header-pic">
            <div style="background-image:url(${data.pic_url})" valign="bottom" class="card-header"><\/div>
            <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
                <p class="parish-item">${data.name}<\/p>
                <p class="distance">${data.distance.toFixed(5)} km away<\/p>
            <\/div>
        <\/div>
    <\/li>
    `)
    .join('<hr>\n');
});
```

Comment: Hi @trincot, I am almost at the end of the project. But am stuck somewhere. I want to be able to retrieve the document id for each document  in my firestore and pass it as an attribute value in each of my <li> tage I have tried all possible means but am unable. Your help will be appreciated

Comment: The comment section is not intended for follow-up questions. I suggest you ask a new question, where you provide all necessary info to see what you have tried and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the approch used in below fiddle.

> https://jsfiddle.net/techtichemant/dh6nu7m0/4/

```
  <ul> 
            <li><div>   apple</div></li> 
                        <li><div>   pinapple</div></li>
                        <li><div>   mango   </div></li> 
            <li><div>   banana</div></li>
        </ul> 
        <br> 

        <center> 
            <button> 
                click here 
            </button> 
        </center> 

        <p id = "triger_elem" style =  
            "text-align:center; color:green; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;"> 
        </p>
```

```
function Ascending_sort(a, b) { 
                return ($(b).find('div').text().toUpperCase()) <  
                    ($(a).find('div').text().toUpperCase()) ? 1 : -1;  
            } 
            $('button').on('click', function() { 
                $("ul li").sort(Ascending_sort).appendTo('ul'); 
                $("#triger_elem").text("sorted"); 
            });
```

a small demonstration of your issue

Comment: This will not help my case since I am sorting numbers and not texts

Comment: oh.. np. glad that you have got your solution :-)